# NSDateFormatter giving me time 4 hours ahead

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm converting a string "Jun 11, 2012 9:30 PM" to an NSDate and I keep getting 4 hours ahead for some reason. The funny thing is I'm using this same string to feed a UIDatePicker in a detailed view where I have to do the same conversion, and the UIDatePicker renders the time fine. Only when I now try to NSLog it in my main and detailed view do I have problems.

This is in my views :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy h:mma"];  
NSDate *dateFromString = [[[NSDate alloc] init]autorelease];

NSLog(@"DATE %@", _date);

dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:_date];

NSLog(@"NSDATEFROMSTRING %@", dateFromString);
```

NSLog returns :

```
2012-06-11 00:02:09.136 LocalDeals[78090:207] DATE Jun 11, 2012 9:30 PM
2012-06-11 00:02:09.137 LocalDeals[78090:207] NSDATEFROMSTRING 2012-06-12 01:30:00 +0000
```

Even when I add:

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
```

I still get the same results from any time I choose. Any ideas? This is on the simulator by the way and yes my Region Format is set to United States.

Comment: Tnq.Your question helped me to solve my issue +1 for you & for the person who answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you NSLog an NSDate it will print the time as a GMT time zone
In order to see the correct data you will have to convert the NSDate to string using `stringFromDate`

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [[[NSDate alloc] init]autorelease];

NSLog(@"DATE %@", _date);

//Instead of nslog directly, use this stringFromDate:remindOn
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
NSLog(@"date is %@", str); //This will log the correct data
```

The problem you are getting is not in the NSDate but it is in Logging it
**UPDATE** In order to save the data to a file or database i would suggest that you save it like this

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval  = [dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Now when you read it again from the database you would do

```
NSDate *data = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval]
```

Comment: stringFromDate is not giving me the format I want. I need to send the date in it's raw form to a database. Thanks for explaining why it (inexplicably) does this though.

Comment: What data type is NSTimeInterval?  Trying to NSLog it with %@ throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I need to send the date in it's raw format in a url string. I can do that with something like NSString *blockDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dateFromString];, and then put that in the URL string. But it gives me the wrong time

Comment: NSInterval is defined as double, so to NSLog it you would do NSLog(@"%f", timeInterval);

Comment: This seems good, but it doesn't seem to be giving me correct minutes for some reason. I always seem to get 06 for minutes after I convert to PHP server side

Comment: can you post the nstimeinterval value itself?

Comment: Most certainly. The time I just did was 9:40am and the NSTimeInterval came out to be 1339422000.000000. The only PHP server side processing I did on that time was date("Y-m-d H:m:s", $date), which I don't think would change anything. The modified date came out to 2012-06-11 09:06:00. Clearly not 9:40 am.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12391/discussion-between-omar-abdelhafith-and-john-bowlinger)

Comment: This problem is solved. Going from my last comment, I basically changed my PHP from date("Y-m-d H:m:s", $date) to date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date) which gave me the correct format to input into a MySQL database with a type of datetime. This was all thanks to the help of Omar.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will show your time with your time zone:

```
NSString *_date = @"Jun 11, 2012 9:30 PM";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy h:mma"];  
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy h:mma Z"];  

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSLog(@"DATE %@", _date);

dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:_date];

NSLog(@"NSDATEFROMSTRING %@", dateFromString);
NSLog(@"NSDATEFROMSTRING %@", [formatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
NSLog(@"NSDATEFROMSTRING %@", [formatter2 stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```

Result:

```
DATE Jun 11, 2012 9:30 PM
NSDATEFROMSTRING 2012-06-12 04:30:00 +0000
NSDATEFROMSTRING June 11, 2012 9:30PM
NSDATEFROMSTRING June 11, 2012 9:30PM -0700
```

If you Google for UTC Time now, it does give you a time that is close to the second line in the output, which confirms it is printing out the time as a UTC time.

(We are in different time zone and `dateFromString` is interpreting the time in the string as your local time.)