# Getting wrong date from NSDateFormatter from dateFromString Method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get `NSDate` object from string . I use the fallowing code

```
NSString *st1=@"4:39 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *dateobj=[dateFormatter dateFromString:st1];
NSLog(@"Date from string 4:39 AM is %@",dateobj);
```

But it gives wrong output such like as

**Date from string 4:39 AM is 1969-12-31 23:09:00 +0000**

What is the exact way to get the `NSDate` object from this type of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont base your result on NSLoging `NSDate`, since logging it will give you the time in GMT
Please refer to my answer on this question [NSDateFormatter giving me time 4 hours ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974496/nsdateformatter-giving-me-time-4-hours-ahead/10974601#10974601)

For example if you want to fire a `UILocalNotification` at 4:39 am you would do the following

```
NSCalendar* myCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [myCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                             fromDate:[NSDate date]];
//4:39 Am
[components setHour: 4]; //4 am
[components setMinute: 39];//39 minutes
[components setSecond: 0];// 0 seconds
NSDate *myDate = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy h:mma"];  
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];

NSLog(@"date is %@", myDate); //This will log the correct data but in GMT time zone
NSLog(@"date is %@", str); //This will log the correct data

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = myDate;
```

Comment: I want to set UILocal Notification on today 4:39 AM ? How it is possible to set firedate from string @"4:39 AM"

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED check the updated i done to my answer, also please dont forget to accept and/or upvote if the answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. You did specify only time and not date. This way, date is assumed to be the beginning of computer age 1970/1/1 (computer zero time). `NSLog` then shows it depending on your time zone (GMT-5).

If you want a better answer, you have to specify what output you want. The code is correct ant the result is correct, too.

Comment: I want to set local notification on today which he had time